# javascript setTimeout, page looks like is endlessly loading (firefox)

Tags: javascript, firefox, settimeout

```
var checkTextValue = setTimeout(function() {
var textVal = $('p').text();
if (textVal == 'expectedValue'){
    callback();
} else {
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 10);
}
},10);
```

i have this code,it works just fine but the problem is that in firefox the page looks like is endlessly loading.

Comment: Aside from endlessly loading, what event are you expecting to update the paragraph's text? Does it ever get updated? Depending on what you're doing 10ms delay may not be enough for the other events to occur (although not likely in modern systems).

Comment: in my real code i get that paragraph from an iframe and the paragraph is printed in that iframe by a php page as a success result, that's what i'm looking for in that paragraph...(php prints 1 for success and 0 for failure)

Comment: you might consider replacing the iframe by an ajax request...

Comment: that php uploads pictures...so i can't do it with an ajax request from what i know

Comment: So your problem is not caused by setTimeout at all, most likely by the iframe. Perhaps post another question describing what you're doing with the iframe and asking for alternative suggestions that don't make the page look like it's 'endlessly loading'?

Answer (score 1):

Looks kind of useless... I mean setTimeout(checkTextValue, 10); - what are you setting there? checkTextValue is just a timeout ID, nothing else... No idea why FF would load endlessly, simply because the code is faulty...

Comment: this is a small scale version of my original script, i updated it (arguments.callee), and it really works...the only problem is that permanently loading status in FF

Comment: var check = function () { console.log('chack'); setTimeout(chack, 1000); }
check();

This code perfectly works without this loading issue (the same thing oversimplified). So try it out. If it works - that means that you prolly need to increase the timeout itself.

Comment: Btw, your code works in my FF 3.5.4pre Win. So, uhm... check your FF? :) No loading 'look-alike' symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

That is because it is endlessly loading. Basically you do recursion and start another instance every ten milliseconds. Given enough time, I think it also is possible to kill your browser with this code.

Try using an `onchange`-eventhandler on your input field instead.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's every ten milliseconds, not seconds

Comment: ok, but the function is called every ten milliseconds until the textVal gets the expected value. this is how i interpret this code...

Answer (score -1):

I think its a case of recusrsion. Google 'recusrion' for more clues. Just kidding. checkTextValue will be running indefinitely unless the value is 'expectedValue'.